# web toolkit that does all of this?

Tags: ajax, toolkit

Is there an ajax toolkit that does:

1. A star rating system
2. captcha
3. file upload
4. auto-complete

I am planning a new social website.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the frameworks can do what you are looking for, but the the answer to "Which is better" is hard to define. And, unfortunately, the frameworks are developing so quickly that a comparison is only valid for a short amount of time.

The highest rated question on this topic was asked about a year ago, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs.

Hopefully that can give you some background, so you can make a more informed decision.